# Display Nested Categories with Single Model

Tags: python, django

```
class ProductCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category_image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='categories/product/imgs/', verbose_name=_("Category Image"), blank=True, null=True,
        help_text=_("Please use our recommended dimensions: 120px X 120px"))
    category_description = models.TextField(verbose_name=_("Category Description"))
    slug = models.SlugField(
        blank=True, null=True, allow_unicode=True, unique=True, verbose_name=_("Slugfiy"))
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

In website home page I need to show the categories in nested menu.So Can anybody help me to do it..?

Comment: I used to use django-categories which is kind of representing trees with relational databases, it uses django-mptt under the hood. It offers a special widget / admin change list which allows for unfolding hierarchical items.

Comment: in what context is the display that you want to achieve supposed to be? Is it on a specific page, the admin interface, something else?

Comment: In website home page I need to show the categories in nested menu

Comment: ok also include example data, what it looks like now (share the template) - and then describe how you would rather the template worked. you should also share the view function for the template